Chromadb - how to extract entire chromadb collection using batchwise get method to get collection with metadata and embeddings?
I want to move from chromadb to qdrant.
For that I want to extract embeddings, metadata, documents from chromadb.
One way I found was to use get method.
result = vector_db.get(include=["embeddings", "metadatas", "documents"])

But the problem is it will crash the memory cause I've 100k data points.
Is there any batchwise get method where I can extract data or peek method with specific indexing or query method without specifying embeddings where we can specify index number and it'll fetch everything?
